# Dynamically add meta description in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, meta-tags

I'm using Angular 5,I want to add meta tags dynamically

I Tried below code it is showing in inspect element (console), but it is not showing on source code

```
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer, Meta} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
private meta: Meta) { 

    this.meta.addTags([
             {property: 'og:title', content: 'this is a content'},
    ])
}
```

[this is my elements (console) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glLRf.png)

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. The client side template render cannot change the markup (from the index.html), it changes the DOM. This is not a thing from Angular, this is how javascript works.

Comment: Is there any other way for meta tags ?